# Animating Ng-view

Tags: animation, dart, angular-dart

I have been trying for too long to try and get  transitions animated as I can in angular.js, with no success.

ng-view works, I can move between views with no issue and the url updates correctly, but no animation is triggered.

My HTML for this is:

```dart
<div flex horizontal wrap layout>
    <ng-view class="slide"></ng-view>
</div>
```

My css (taken from http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/code) is:

```dart
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter,
.slide.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slide.ng-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}
.slide.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.slide.ng-leave-active {
    left: -100%;
}
```

and I am including the animation module:

```dart
...
import 'package:angular/animate/module.dart';

import 'package:ch_padart/main_module.dart'; //Main Module set

void main() {
  initPolymer()
  .run(() {
    applicationFactory()
    .addModule(new NodeBindModule())
    .addModule(new MainModule())
    .addModule(new AnimationModule()) //<-- installed animation module
    .run();
  });
}
...
```